# How to prove $\sup(f + g) ≥ \sup (f) + \inf (g)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $D$ is a nonempty bounded subset of reals. Let $f:D\to\Bbb R$ and $g:D\to\Bbb R$.

How to prove $\sup(f + g) \geq \sup (f) + \inf (g)$?

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea where to begin, as you can see the answer is very short, and i didn't think it would be worth it posting as i knew it didn't lead to a proper conclusion. But i will try harder next time :)

Comment: The answer is short. Did it provide you with all the necessary detail? Do you 'understand' now?  These are questions we cannot answer since you gave no detail on your issues. If you want more than an answer, then you should indicate what your difficulties are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $x$, $f(x)+\inf g \leq f(x)+g(x) \leq \sup (f+g)$. Hence $\sup f(x)+\inf g \leq f(x)+g(x) \leq \sup (f+g)$.

Comment: Does the supremum operator on $f(x)$ in the second line preserve the inequality simply because of the argument that the first line holds for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, if $\forall x, f(x) \leq a$, then $\sup f(x) \leq a$, by definition of a lowest bound (recall that $\sup$ is the greatest lower bound)

Comment: @LJNG for the reply

Comment: The second inequality should just read $$\sup f+\inf g  \leq \sup (f+g).$$  You cannot make any sense of the middle expression $f(x)+g(x)$ since after you take the supremum there is no $x$ under consideration.