# $\inf\{f (x)+g(x)\} \leq \inf\{f (x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} \leq \sup\{f (x)+g(x)\} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

**I know that there are lots of similar questions on the website, but my question here is more specific, and I think my argument has some flaws.**

If $f, g$ are both defined on the set $E$, then \begin{equation*}\inf\{f(x)\}+\inf\{g(x)\} \leq \inf\{f (x)+g(x)\} \leq \inf\{f (x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} \leq \sup\{f (x)+g(x)\} \leq \sup\{f (x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\}\end{equation*}

Dealing with the **second** and the **third** inequality, my argument is since below holds for all $x\in E$

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x)\leq f(x)+\sup\{g(x)\}\leq{\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}}
$$

Hence,

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x)\leq {\color{red}{\inf\{f(x)\}}}+\sup\{g(x)\}\leq{\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}}
$$

This idea is similar to [Kavi Rama Murthy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965593/how-to-prove-supf-g-%E2%89%A5-sup-f-inf-g)

I was convinced this argument worked, but if this argument is correct then a similar argument could also apply to the below to have

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x)\implies \inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq \inf\{f(x)\}+\inf\{g(x)\}
$$

However we know this is not true, it should be another way around. So what exactly the argument should be in answering

$$
\inf\{f (x)+g(x)\} \leq \inf\{f (x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} \leq \sup\{f (x)+g(x)\} 
$$

and what should be the argument for dealing with the link that I posted [Kavi Rama Murthy's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2965593/how-to-prove-supf-g-%E2%89%A5-sup-f-inf-g)

---

re-edit: WTS

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq \inf\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\}\leq{\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}}
$$

we know that

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x) \leq{\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}}
$$

Hence we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x) &\leq f(x)+\sup\{g(x)\}\\
\inf\{\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\}= \inf\{f(x)+g(x)\} &\leq \inf\{f(x)+\sup\{g(x)\}\}\\
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\} &\leq \inf\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} \quad\text{$\sup\{g(x)\}$ is constant }
\end{align*}
$$

Similarly

$$
\begin{align*}
\inf\{f(x)\}+g(x)&\leq f(x)+g(x)  \leq \sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}\\
\sup\{\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\}&\leq \sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}  = \sup\{\sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}\}\\
\inf\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} &\leq \sup\{f(x)+g(x)\} \quad\text{$\inf\{f(x)\}$ is constant }
\end{align*}
$$

Overall

$$
\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq \inf\{f(x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\}\leq \sup\{f(x)+g(x)\}
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate / show your work on the "similar argument could also apply to the below"? $\quad $(Depending on your argument,) note that $ A \leq C $ and $B\leq C$ does not imply that $ A \leq B$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for your reply. 

My original question's argument is "Since this inequality holds for all $x$, so such inequality is preserved under an extra operation $\inf\{f(x)\}$ (highlighted in red) ". 


The similar argument just "this inequality $\inf\{f(x)+g(x)\}\leq f(x)+g(x)$ holds for all $x$, then apply $\inf$ on the RHS again should be fine....."

Comment: Please work that through slowly / write it up in full. I believe your misconception is in assuming that we can selectively applying the INF function to partial terms. In particular, Kavi's argument requires that $\sup \{ g(x) \} $ is a constant, which allows us to say that $ \inf \{ f(x) + \sup \{ g(x) \}  \} = \inf\{ f(x) \} + \sup \{ g(x) \}$ (which is the step that I think you skipped). $\quad$ Applying it in this case, all that we can say is $ \inf \{ f(x) + g(x) \} \leq \inf \{ f(x) + g(x) \}$, which is trivially true.

Comment: @CalvinLin does my re-edited answer look good to you? It seems there's no way to solve all inequality at once.

Comment: Please choose a shorter more descriptive title for your question

Comment: I also recommend you say at the beginning what you are trying to prove, rather than waiting until the middle.

Comment: @MW I had a misconception that could have selective operator $\inf,\sup$ on one side if prescribe inequality holds for all $x$. you may see I was asking what correct reasoning argument should follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation in

> $$\inf\{f (x)+g(x)\} \leq \inf\{f (x)\}+\sup\{g(x)\} \leq \sup\{f (x)+g(x)\}$$

is very unhelpful, since it leads to you writing elsewhere expressions like $f(x)+\sup\{g(x)\}$, where $x$ means two different things in the same expression.  This is why much of the argumentation you are using doesn't quite add up.

We will therefore instead use the notation

$$\inf(f+g) \leq \inf f +\sup g \leq \sup (f +g).\tag{1}$$

To prove this, observe that for all $x$, $$f(x)+g(x)\leq f(x)+\sup g.$$  Taking the infimum of both sides gives us the first inequality in (1).

On the other hand, we also have for all $x$, $$\inf f + g(x) \leq f(x)+g(x),$$ so taking the supremum of both sides gives us the second inequality in (1).

##### Remark

The [answer you linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2965598/1210477) also gets into trouble with a similar notational confusion, in which it is written $$\sup f(x)+\inf g \leq f(x)+g(x) \leq \sup (f+g).$$
Note that to the extent it makes sense, the first inequality is false whenever $f$ is nonconstant and $g$ is constant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was re-editing my answer, is that looks fine?

Comment: @LJNG I think the re-edit has the right logic, but it is extremely hard to follow, and I strongly recommend you do not use notation like that.  You are using $x$ to mean two different things in the same string of inequalities, which is a notational disaster.